# Where to find IT freelancers, willing to relocate to join security cleared projects at EU agencies?

Tags: eu, eu-citizens, europe, job-hunting, career

I'm a sourcer looking for adventurous freelancers, who like travelling to differnet European cities and would like to obtain security clearance and join short- term and long-term EU projects. Can I post a job offer here? Is there any group that would be best for this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m going to go with “no”. Please read the Tour and Help pages to see which kind of questions are appropriate for this site.

There are sites aplenty for posting job ads - I suggest that you use those. This is a Q&A site.

Comment: I wonder, being a moderator - why didn't you just close the question as off topic?

Comment: I try to avoid closing questions, unless they are actual spam. And I can't VOTE to close, as a moderator's vote to close is considered an actual close. So I downvoted the question and left an answer telling the OP why it was not the right place to post such content. Plus - the OP asked politely first, rather than spamming us. I felt that it would be more courteous to answer before closing. Now that there are four votes to close, I put the fifth and final vote in and it's been closed.

Comment: IMHO answering and voting to close should be mutually exclusive. If you think you can answer - then the question shouldn't be closed. If the question should be closed - clearly you don't have a proper answer.

Comment: The question was "can I post a job post here?" so I answered "no". If the question had been asked on 'meta' then it would not have been closed at all, I am sure. But there are occasions where a question has had answers and then been closed later